# How to display stars accroding to feedback in ionic mobile app using angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to display the stars according to feedback given by customer in my html page.
I am calling an api in which stars count is coming as 1,2,3,4,5 depending upon the feedback given.

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to show up to 5 stars. And use icon-styles to show

1. stars where rating covers full star
2. stars where rating covers half star - 3.5
3. stars where rating does not cover any star

```html
<ion-button [ngStyle]="{'width' : fontSize, 'height' : fontSize}" *ngFor="let index of iconsArray" id="{{index}}"  icon-only (click)="changeRating($event)">
    <ion-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':defaultColor , 'font-size' : fontSize }" name="{{(halfStar ==='true' && (rating - index > 0) && (rating - index <= 0.5)) ? halfIcon : (index < rating) ?  activeIcon : defaultIcon }}"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Comment: what is iconsarray here?

Comment: @KumariSaloni `IconArray` is your rating array.  from your api. if you are getting it as number convert it to array.

Comment: @KumariSaloni. this is my default icon array
  iconsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
match it with the rating from Backend

Comment: Could you provide your ts for changeRating($event)?

Answer (score 1):

[ionic-rating-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-rating-component) it is a npm package. It's very easy to use. I'm providing the link you also read the documentation and proceed as you want thanks.

```
<ionic-rating-component
          activeColor="#ffc409"
          readonly="true"
          [rating]="data.rating.rate"
          fontSize = "32px"
          >
</ionic-rating-component>
```

For further assistance please let me know thanks.

Comment: Yes, this documentation is very nice. Thank you so much for sharing this.
But in my case, I am not doing this.
In my case, actually I am calling an api and in the response I am getting rating value as 1,2,3,4 or 5 depending on the feedback given by customer.
So I just have to show the no. of stars according to the feedback given.
If customer has given a feedback as 3, then i have to show 3 stars and 2 star-outline. 
How can i achieve this please tell?

Comment: This is very easy. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I add simple code. you just pass the number of your rating to the property of ion-rating-component.

Comment: Upvoting for easy documentation. There is also an alternative : https://github.com/RodainaMohamed/ionic-rating.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib This will be good But it's 2 years old and have 5 issues. I have provided no issue and updated last month ago. Now up to you, you chose a better library or not. thanks.